# Apple App store release task 1.183 Errors out. The current operating system is not capable of running this task

Tags: tfsbuild, testflight

Our TFS ios builds have started failing in the Apple app store release task. The error recorded is

The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.

Version is 1.183

Fast lane is also updated but no luck. The error does not seem to point to any version issues though.

Below is the log from the build logs from agent mac machine.

```
[2021-02-21 00:43:34Z ERR  StepsRunner] Caught exception from step: System.Exception: The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.
```

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.d__1.MoveNext()

Any one dealt with similar issues, will appreciate inputs here?

Comment: Did you mean you use [Apple App Store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store&ssr=false#overview) extension? Could you share your pipeline? In addition, please set variable `system.debug` to `true` to share the detailed log (mask the personal information).

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check the build agent you use in this build, to see whether the build use the agent installed on the MacOS computer. The tasks install and use fastlane tools. fastlane requires Ruby 2.0.0 or above and recommends having the latest Xcode command line tools installed on the MacOS computer.

Comment: So it turned out to be agent version issue. We updated to 2.174 (could not go all the way to latest because of our tfs is http and latest versions did not like http) and it worked fine. As part of the analysis we did update xcode, fastlane etc...